# Spring Security-acl. Users do not receive permission

Tags: spring, spring-security, acl

It seems to be all right. Authorization is working, and users get the roles. I protected the methods of using annotations (for example @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#post, 'READ')") ), it works and I get access denied. I created a database in which he described the rights of users to objects. I created a database which contains the user's permission on objects.

My problem is that after the user's authorization, it is not getting permissions, and even if the user has the authority to object, he gets access denied. Also, I noticed that after a user login in the log file of the server should get a string which will write what permission he got, but I have no such line.

Pieces of my files:

**web.xml**

```
...
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/acl-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml 
    </param-value>
</context-param>...
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    ...
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>

<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven />
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bla-bla.bla.controllers" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
...
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
    ...
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
    access-denied-page="/auth/denied.html">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login.html" access="permitAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/auth/login.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.html?error=true"
        default-target-url="/index.html" />
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/auth/login.html" logout-url="/auth/logout.html" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="pswEncoder" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="userService"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiJboss" />
    <property name="usersByUsernameQuery"
        value="SELECT login, pass, enabled FROM accounts WHERE login=?" />
    <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery"
        value="SELECT login, authority FROM accounts WHERE login=?" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"
    id="pswEncoder" />
...
```

**acl-context.xml**

```
    ...
<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler"
    p:permissionEvaluator-ref="permissionEvaluator"
    p:roleHierarchy-ref="roleHierarchy" />

<bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator" id="permissionEvaluator">
    <constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService" id="aclService">
    <constructor-arg ref="jndiJboss"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="lookupStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy">
    <constructor-arg ref="jndiJboss"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="aclAuthorizationStrategy"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="auditLogger"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="jndiJboss" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/JBossDB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="aclCache" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
            <property name="cacheManager">
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"/>
            </property>
            <property name="cacheName" value="aclCache"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="aclAuthorizationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="auditLogger" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger"/>


<bean id="roleHierarchy"  class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
...
```

**An example of a protected method of the controller**

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/post/delete.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#post, 'READ')")
public String delete(final Post post) {
    //some actions
    return "post/view";
}
```

In what could be the problem?

**UPD**. My problem was in the wrong filling acl_object_identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post the code that uses the ACLs (secured method invocations) and also highlight those classes in the Spring config files. Also, why are you placing the `<security:global-method-security />` element in your MVC config file?

Comment: I edited my first post and there he put the example of the method.
«also highlight those classes in the Spring config files.» what are you? I just have a folder of controllers, in which the search for annotations.
Earlier I posted <security:global-method-security /> in the file acl-context.xml, but it did not work, annotations were ignored, when I moved to a file mvc-dispatcher-servlet. xml annotation began to work, it's very strange, because the file acl-context.xml loaded. Maybe that's my problem? Maybe acl-context.xml file is not processed correctly? But why ...

Comment: Ok, since you apply PreAuthorize to controllers, placing the <security:global-method-security /> element in your MVC config makes sense. Other than that: 1) Make sure PreAuthorize is really applied (proxy or AspectJ-based security interceptors are invoked). 2) Have a look at your aclAuthorizationStrategy bean, you have three items in the constructor argument list with ROLE_ADMIN? 3) Are you sure you are not getting cached permissions from AclCache?

Comment: 1) I need to analyze my log file? Or are there other ways?
2) AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl is the default implementation of AclAuthorizationStrategy. Notice the constructor accepts three arguments. Based on the Spring Security API, constructor signature is as follows: public AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(GrantedAuthority[] auths).Right?
3) Hmm ... I did not think about it. How can I check it?

Comment: 1) Yes, make sure Spring logs at DEBUG. 2) I meant this: why are you passing the same GrantedAuthorityImpl (ROLE_ADMIN) three times? 3) Try using a null AclCache. Furthermore, the constructor you are using for BasicLookupStrategy is deprecated (have a look at the version with PermissionGrantingStrategy as argument). Also have a look at https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/tree/master/samples/contacts for an example on using ACLs.